# Mochasoft TN3270 access from 2 systems

Tags: emulation, mainframe

I have a mainframe emulator 'Mochasoft TN3270' installed in my learning centre.
I have installed Mochasoft TN3270 in my windows 7 laptop too. 
Both versions are trial for a period of 30 days.
I have a username and password to access the server in my learning centre through an IP.

Can I use the same IP,username,password to access the emulator from my home laptop?
Will it conflict with the usage from my learning centre?

Comment: I am able to login from my laptop. Will it conflict with the system in learning centre?

Comment: No. There is no relationship between the two installations of software. Whether you are actually "clean" with the licensing is down to the specific documentation provided to you for the trial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user and password are the MainFrame user/password, and not the MochaSoft terminal software. 
There shouldn't be a problem accessing the MainFrame via other computer. 
If you are looking for a non limited emulator,S3270 is an open source terminal software, which provide similar functionality to MochaSoft without trial limitation.

Comment: Our software uses S3270, and it's a reliable project.

Comment: It's packaged in the same bundle, so for user interface X3270 should be used

Comment: And we can get rid of the comments, as they become unneeded.